# Can the http://meta.stackexchange.com/ in the Community user’s network profile page be changed to https://…?

Tags: feature-request, community-user, network-profile, ssl

The network profile of the [Community user](https://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), mentions `http://meta.stackexchange.com/`.

[image: Screenshot of the network profile of Community: “on the server farm http://meta.stackexchange.com/”]

Can this be changed to `https://meta.stackexchange.com`? On copying and browsing it is automatically redirected to `https://` but it’d be nice if it were changed in the network profile, too.

Comment: A script should be devised and all applicable changes to ***all*** of Community's accounts should be done to fulfil this BR, each account has an inconsistent choice of *home* account and uses the http protocol. Examples: https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community https://meta.serverfault.com/users/-1/community  https://superuser.com/users/-1/community  https://meta.superuser.com/users/-1/community

Comment: Random info: Mods can edit the profile of Community bot.